# Python Selenium Selector fails - why?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

[Imgur image with code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSCrm.png)

I have trouble locating the correct selectors. Working on a practise case where the task is to search and download images. Why did all my attempts at selecting the links on imgur fail? I was so sure that "image-list-link" is the common denomenator for the images, but I just cannot figure out how to use it properly.

There´s something I'm missing when trying to use these scraping options. Grateful for any help!

```
#! Python3
# 12_Practise_ISD is a script that downloads images from a website

import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://imgur.com/')

# going to the site & entering search term
searchElem = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"Searchbar-textInput")
searchElem.send_keys('cox-farms')
searchElem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(3)

# selecting pix - all failed
#img = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"image-list-link")
#img = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="image-list-link"]')
#img = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//class[@id='imagelist']/href")
#img = browser.find_element(By.ID, "imagelist")
#img = browser.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, '/gallery')
#img = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "image-list-link")
#img = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'img.src')
#img = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'img.image-list-link')

#this one finally worked!
src =[]
images = browser.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "img")

for img in images:
    src.append(img.get_attribute('src'))

browser.close()
print(src)
```

Comment: Trying waiting for the element to load, using `WebDriverWait`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root cause of the issue:** Your code is too fast to run and try to locate the web elements before even the web page gets loaded completely. In such cases, you need to use Selenium's `waits`, refer the code below to understand how you can use them in your code.

**Refer the below refactored code using Selenium's `waits`:**

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://imgur.com/')
browser.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30)

searchElem = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,"Searchbar-textInput")))
searchElem.send_keys('cox-farms')
searchElem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
# time.sleep(3)
src =[]
images = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, "img")))

for img in images:
    src.append(img.get_attribute('src'))

browser.close()
print(src)
```

**Console Result:**

```
['https://i.imgur.com/1xHnP8db.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/Pas9F0jb.jpg']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**References:** [Selenium Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/)